# SwiftUI: Prevent Text from expanding view outside available bounds

Tags: ios, swiftui, uihostingcontroller

I'm encountering an issue where `Text`, depending on its contents, is causing the SwiftUI view to grow larger than the available space rather than wrapping a word to another line. I think it's just a bug (FB11809780) but I'm interested in finding a workaround if possible.

The `Text` is within a `Form` using the `columns` style which will place it in the second column. I embed the `ContentView` in a `UIHostingController` and give its `view` a fixed constant width. In the screenshots you can see depending on the string it can cause the SwiftUI view to grow larger than the containing `UIView` - it bleeds out left and right. The second screenshot's text does not cause the issue because it wraps such that the width isn't larger than the available space. It seems to me as if there’s an internal issue calculating how much width is available before it needs to wrap, so it's allowed to be a bit larger than what's actually available.

I've tried adding `.fixedSize` to the Text but that didn't impact its behavior.

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var featureEnabled = false

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Toggle(isOn: $featureEnabled) {
                    Text("Feature")
                }
                
                if featureEnabled {
                    FormView()
                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
        .background(Color(UIColor.secondarySystemBackground))
    }
}

struct FormView: View {
    @State private var selectedOption = 1
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Picker(selection: $selectedOption, label: Text("Option:")) {
                Text("One").tag(1)
                Text("Two").tag(2)
                Text("Three").tag(3)
            }
            
            switch selectedOption {
            case 1:
                Text("Hellllllo world and all those who inhabit it. Hello universe and all those who inhabit it.")
            case 2:
                Text("This line of text does not replicate the issue.")
            case 3:
                Text("This really really really really really really long line of text does not replicate the issue either.")
            default:
                fatalError()
            }
        }
        .formStyle(.columns)
        .font(.system(size: 14))
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let vc = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView())
        addChild(vc)
        vc.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(vc.view)
        vc.didMove(toParent: self)
        
        let separatorView = UIView()
        separatorView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        separatorView.backgroundColor = .label
        view.addSubview(separatorView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            vc.view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 320),
            vc.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            vc.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            vc.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            separatorView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1),
            separatorView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vc.view.leadingAnchor),
            separatorView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            separatorView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
        ])
    }

}
```

Comment: Odd. Looks like a bug related to sizing/wrapping strings with narrow characters i.e. "i,l,(,)".  Starting case 1 with "Hello big world" wraps correctly yet starting with "Hello lil world" doesn't.